# Getting results for multi_match cross_fields query in elasticsearch with custom analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic search 5.3 server with products.
Each product has a 14 digit product code that has to be searchable by the following rules. The complete code should match as well as a search term with only the last 9 digits, the last 6, the last 5 or the last 4 digits.

In order to achieve this I created a custom analyser which creates the appropriate tokens at index time using the pattern capture token filter. This seems to be working correctly. The _analyse API shows that the correct terms are created.

To fetch the documents from elastic search I'm using a multi_match cross_fields bool query to search a number of fields simultaneously.

When I have a query string that has a part that matches a product code and a part that matches any of the other fields no results are returned, but when I search for each part separately the appropriate results are returned. Also when I have multiple parts spanning any of the fields except the product code the correct results are returned.

**My maping and analyzer:**

```
PUT /store
{
    "mappings": {
        "products":{
            "properties":{
                "productCode":{
                    "analyzer": "ProductCode",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard",
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "description": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "remarks": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "ProductCodeNGram": {
                    "type": "pattern_capture",
                    "preserve_original": "true",
                    "patterns": [
                        "\\d{5}(\\d{9})",
                        "\\d{8}(\\d{6})",
                        "\\d{9}(\\d{5})",
                        "\\d{10}(\\d{4})"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "ProductCode": {
                    "filter": ["ProductCodeNGram"],
                    "type": "custom",
                    "preserve_original": "true",
                    "tokenizer": "standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The query**

```
GET /store/products/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
               {
                   "multi_match": {
                      "query": "[query_string]",
                      "fields": ["productCode", "description", "remarks"],
                      "type": "cross_fields",
                      "operator": "and"
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample data**

```
POST /store/products
{
    "productCode": "999999123456789",
    "description": "Foo bar",
    "remarks": "Foobar"
}
```

The following query strings all return one result:

"456789", "foo", "foobar", "foo foobar".

But the query_string "foo 456789" returns no results.

I am very curious as to why the last search does not return any results. I am convinced that it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing a cross_fields over fields with different analysers. Cross fields only works for fields using the same analyser. It in fact groups the fields by analyser before doing the cross fields. You can find more information in this documentation.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#_literal_cross_field_literal_and_analysis

Answer (score 0):

Although `cross_fields` needs the same analyzer across the fields it operates on, I've had luck using the [tie_breaker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_tuning_best_fields_queries.html#_tie_breaker) parameter to allow other fields (that use different analyzers) to be weighed for the total score.
This has the added benefit of allowing per-field boosting to be calculated in the final score, too.

Here's an example using your query:

```
GET /store/products/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
               {
                   "multi_match": {
                      "query": "[query_string]",
                      "fields": ["productCode", "description", "remarks"],
                      "type": "cross_fields",
                      "tie_breaker": 1   # You may need to tweak this
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I also removed the `operator` field, as I believe using the "AND" operator will cause fields that don't have the same analyzer to be scored inappropriately.